# Understanding protobuff protocol

Tags: python, http, python-requests, protocol-buffers, mitmproxy

I'm just doing some reverse engineering exercise and have ran across `application/x-protobuff` protocol..
I am currently sniffing network calls from redfin using mitmproxy. I see a endpoint for a result, however the response is unstructured JSON formatted data with content type `application/x-protobuff` After doing a bit of research, I found out that protobuff uses a schema to map the data internally, and I am assuming the schema also sits in the client somewhere, called `.proto` file.

[SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbWR1.png)

To validate my assumption on what that screenshot tells is that

I can see there is a response header called `X-ProtoBuf-Schema` is that the the location where the schma would be located, the same schema I can use to decrypt the response data? How would I go on about reading that data in a more structured manner?

I am able to make a request using requests to that endpoint, just gives me protobuffers.

PS: This is what the JSON format looks like
https://pastebin.com/LY51X9KZ

Comment: Usually programs and apps do never contain the .proto file. This file is used to generate the protobuf model classes (source code) which is include din client and server application. If you want to regenerate the .proto file you have to manually reverse engineer the app. In the old times when protobuf2 was still used Android apps contained a lot info about the original .proto file (such as field names and other names) but nowadays using the minimized model classes generated by protobuf3 do not contain much data from the original .proto file.

Answer (score 2):

"and I am assuming the schema also sits in the client somewhere, called .proto file." - I wouldn't assume that at all; the client, once built, doesn't need the .proto - the generated code is used instead of any explicit schema. If a site is *publishing* a schema, it is probably a serialized `FileDescriptorSet` from google/protobuf/descriptor.proto, which contains the *intent* of the .proto, but as data.

Comment: So - From server side what they do is they use the .proto schema defined in their server, given that it produces a generated code on server side which is then served to client for further deserialization?   So technically for me to correctly understand how that JSON is strucutred I'd have to find the generated code and use that to deserialize the data?

Comment: To give you context - My initial approach was to get IPA file and look for .proto file and use that in my python to deserialize the data from redfin. But it appears that given IPA file, I'd use hopper or some sort of similar disassemabler and try to find that `generated code`, then basically mimic that generated code to deserialize any further protobuffer data?

Comment: @Hooopla did you say that the schema URL have you protobuf? That *is* the schema, just not in text form. But: you could also just *ask for the schema*. I've reverse engineered many many schemas, and have tools to help, but: my tools are based on the binary format, not the JSON one

Comment: Not sure if I follow, but my goal was to read the response I posted on SS in a more readable format. I thought using the .proto schema would be the way. The response is basically JSON, but I see the content-type is protobuf. Are you saying that the JSON response itself is the schema? But how come it looks unstructured? I don't see the common key-value pair. How would I do to achieve it that way?

Comment: Marc Gravell, here is the JSON data I am trying to structure. https://pastebin.com/LY51X9KZ

Comment: @HOOOPLA protobuf refers to all of: a schema DSL, a binary encoding format for data in that schema; an opinionated JSON encoding format for data in that schema; it would seem *very unusual* for an endpoint that describes itself as x-protobuf to return JSON, but : everything is fair game. Ultimately, you either need to play with it and figure it out (since reverse engineering), or ask whoever owns the data.